# Nhibernate, updating a child gives new parent

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm new to nhibernate. When I normally update a record (without childs) I just create a new object, set the old ID, change the needed values and update the record. This works.

When I do the same with my child I need to set the parent record else I get a 
could not execute batch command.[SQL: SQL not available] error.

So to do this I create a new parent and set the Id of the parent. I hoped this would do the trick. No exception is thrown, but now I get a new parent record in my database.

Should I always read the to be updated object before updating or are there other ways of doing this? (reading before updating will cost some performance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fighting NHibernate. That's not the proper way to update things. Instead of instantiating the object yourself, it's better to let NHibernate doing so by let it load the existing data from DB and populate the data into the object:

```
// do something
// this will create an object, and populate data from database:
var vehicle = session.Get<Vehicle>(vehicleId);
// change the owner:
vehicle.Owner = "John Smith";
```

Edit 1:
Misread your post. You did say that "reading before updating will cost some performance". I think the performance penalty here is unimportant, unless the code is for absolutely critical purpose.

Edit 2:
There are many parameters that need to be considered in this case. Because you did not post your mapping and data model classes here, so I don't know what is the problem with your code, and this is my educated guess. 
If I were you, I'd used something like this:

```
public class Child
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and mapping:

```
<class name="Child">
    <id name="Id" unsaved-value="0"><generator class="identity" /></id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <many-to-one name="Parent"/>
</class>
<class name="Parent">
    <id name="Id" unsaved-value="0"><generator class="identity" /></id>
    <property name="Name" />
</class>
```

To update Parent without loading old data, this works:

```
session.Update(new Parent { Id = parentId, Name = "Parent 1" });
```

This indeed generates an UPDATE and no SELECT.
Now if you know the child id, parent id and new name for child, you can update the child without incurring any SELECT:

```
session.Update(
    new Child
        {
            Id = childId, 
            Name = "new name", 
            Parent = session.Load<Parent>(parentId)
        });
```

Explanation: by using session.Load, I explicitly told NHibernate not to access database for the Parent record with key parentId, just gives me an uninitialized proxy instead.

So it's possible to achieve what you want, but I don't think it's a good thing to do, sooner or later this code will return to bite you, as this code will produce some unexpected behaviour when the object models grow more complex.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right. Maybe I was trying to save some cpu cycles on the wrong point...

Comment: My answer is not completed. There is at least a way to force NHibernate to update the entity without any considering: using StatelessSession. However, this way will wreck havoc with the session management system of any application which did not prepare for the use of stateless session.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info... And I think you are right about the biting part, so I now first load and then update ;)

Comment: +1 for the "Parent = session.Load<Parent>(parentId)" trick.  Thanks.